# Best practice for creating Ansible users

Tags: ansible

What is the best practice for handling local and remote users in ansible?

My current understand is we have a local and remote machine with a default local user and default admin user on the remote machine.
In the standard case, joe will generate a SSH key pair and copy his public key to the remote '.ssh/authorised_keys'.

```
localhost                                           remotehost
=========                                           ==========
                                                    // sudo root user
user:joe                                            user:admin
passsword:xxx                                       password:admin123
.ssh/id_rsa.pub ----------------------------------> ./ssh/authorised_keys
```

Am i correct to say that the standard ansible.cfg settings would be

```
[defaults]
ansible_user=joe
ansible_ssh_user=admin
private_key_file=/home/pauloconnell/.ssh/id_rsa.pem
```

I came across this ticket which recommends creating an ansible specific user for running the remote commands https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392369/ansible-ssh-private-key-in-source-control

Again, the picture would look like this with a new 'ansible_ssh_user' created on the local machine, its password saved to a vault and
 then the same user created on the remote server with the correct group permissions

```
localhost                                           remotehost
=========                                           ==========
                                                    // sudo root user
user:joe                                            user:admin
passsword:xxx                                       password:admin123
~~.ssh/id_rsa.pub ----------------------------------> ./ssh/authorised_keys~~
user:ansible_ssh_user                               user:ansible_ssh_user    
.ssh/id_rsa.pub ----------------------------------> ./ssh/authorised_keys
```

I'd like to confirm how the config file would change in this case?

```
[defaults]
ansible_user=ansible_ssh_user
ansible_ssh_user=ansible_ssh_user
private_key_file=??
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

- you don't need `ansible_ssh_user` and `ansible_user` as the use of `ansible_ssh_*` variables is deprecated since version 2.0. See [this note](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html):

> Ansible 2.0 has deprecated the “ssh” from ansible_ssh_user, ansible_ssh_host, and ansible_ssh_port to become ansible_user, ansible_host, and ansible_port. If you are using a version of Ansible prior to 2.0, you should continue using the older style variables (ansible_ssh_*). These shorter variables are ignored, without warning, in older versions of Ansible.

- In most cases you don't need to set `private_key_file`.
- You don't need to have `ansible_user` on the control machine. You just need to make sure that your regular user on the control machine can login as `ansible_user` on the remote host, which means you need to copy the ssh key to the remote host.
  `ssh-copy-id ansible_user@remote-host` should be all you need.